# How to calculate friction on body in downwards-facing tube?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

Imagine a falling body, that is in a tube. The tube and body may have a frictional coefficient $\mu$. Generally the frictional force would be given by $\mu R$, where $R$ is the normal reaction. But in this case, how does one calculate $R$? Clearly, there would be a force of friction, but how much?

Here is a drawing to better illustrate my question:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it is applying a horizontal force in the first place ?

Comment: @Bhavay it isn't, but it seems intuitive that the particles of the surface are resisted by the particles of the other surface if they are in contact.

Comment: There is no way to calculate R , from the amount of information you have given. You need more data points to get that

Comment: @silverrahul such as?

Comment: Maybe , how fast it is falling .

Comment: @silverrahul But can that not be obtained from $\sqrt {u^2+2gh}$

Comment: That formula is for a free falling object. Is this body free falling ? If yes, then R will be 0

Comment: @silverrahul But is there no way to find R without finding the diff. of actual velocity and $\sqrt {u^2+2gh}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123499/discussion-between-silverrahul-and-sid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true it seems intuitive that the block will feel a resistive force , since it is in contact and will face electrostatic force.

To calculate R  ,I believe you need to know the acceleration of the block.

**CAse1** : If acceleration is 0.

Then $mg = 2\mu R$

**Case 2** If acceleration is non zero .

then $mg -2\mu R= ma$.

From there you can calculate R.